# Having [srs] and [spaced-repetition] seems a bit repetitive

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition)

> For questions related to a method of study that increases interval of time between reviews of older, more experienced terms.

[srs](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srs)

> Questions about spaced repetition software (SRS) programs, the digital equivalent of paper-based flashcards.

To be pedantic, the latter talks about computer programs, whereas the former doesn't - it can encompass dead tree methodologies such as the [Leitner system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system). But I don't really see the point of having both tags.

There ain't enough space in this Stack Exchange for the two of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have merged these two tags, and made [srs](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srs) a synonym of the (technically) broader [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition).