# Are the tags [spaced-repetition], [flash-cards], and [memorisation] excessive?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition), [flash-cards](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-cards), and [memorization](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memorization) seem very closely related, even though they aren't identical. Is it beneficial to have all three tags, or should we get rid of at least one of them?

For added fun, there's also [anki](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anki), which is a specific program for spaced repetition flash cards.

[Having [srs] and [spaced-repetition] seems a bit repetitive](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/506/having-srs-and-spaced-repetition-seems-a-bit-repetitive) is unrelated - it dealt with the absolutely identical tags "srs" and "spaced-repetition".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my view on what these tags stand for:

- [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition) is for the technique, regardless what "technology" you use for it, paper flash cards, a digital spaced-repetition system or something else.
- [flash-cards](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-cards) refers to either paper or digital flashcards (or flash cards). The tag is close to the previous one but not identical, because there are spaced-repetition techniques that don't rely on flash chards, such as the "gold list method".
- [memorization](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memorization) is for any memorisation technique and is therefore not limited to spaced repetition or flash cards.

I can think of very few topics where [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition) would be appropriate but [flash-cards](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-cards) wouldn't, e.g. the "gold list method" listed above. I can't think any questions where [flash-cards](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-cards) would be appropriate but [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition) wouldn't. **If forced to reduce the number of tags, I would turn [flash-cards](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-cards) into a synonym of the broader concept [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition).**

Having [anki](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anki) seems a bit excessive, since each of the above tags would apply to questions tagged "anki" and it is easy to [search for all content about "anki" that is tagged with `spaced-repetition`](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bspaced-repetition%5D+anki).